# How to get $v=\sqrt{2gh}$ using Lagrangian mechanics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation

If I have a ball that is height $h$ and mass $m$ then its gravitational potential energy $= mgh$ where $g$ is the gravitational constant.

It's kinetic energy is $= \frac{1}{2}mv^2$.

I wish to use Lagrangian mechanics to show that $v=\sqrt{2gh}$ purely using the Euler–Lagrange equation $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left ( \frac {\partial  L}{\partial \dot{x}} \right ) =  \frac {\partial L}{\partial x}\quad ,$$ where $\dot{x} = v$.

I have gotten to the point where $a= -g = \dot{v} = \ddot{x}$, however I am unsure of how to progress from here.

Comment: Lagrangian mechanics is to find the law of motion. x''=g, from there you can prove energy< conservation, but why do it?

Comment: To show that v=… use the energy conservation

Comment: Hint: reversing the vertical axis to mop up some minus signs, $\ddot{x}=g$ has $x_0=0,\,\dot{x}_0=0$ solution $x=\frac12gt^2$, with $x=h$ at a value of $t$ that achieves what value of $\dot{x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Lagrangian $L = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 - m g x$ is independent of time, then the [Beltrami identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity) guarantees that the quantity
$$
C \equiv L - \dot{x} \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}}
$$
is a constant of the motion so long as the system obeys the Euler-Lagrange equations.  In this case, this quantity is
$$
\frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 - m g x - \dot{x} (m \dot{x}) = -\frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 - m g x
$$
which can be recognized as the negative of the energy.  At the launch of the object, we have $C = - \frac{1}{2} m v_0^2$;  at its apogee, we have $C = - mgh$;  and setting these equal to each other yields the desired equation.